# Show a test-tree from package.json script

Tags: ts-jest, react-tsx

Show a test-tree from package.json script

Hello!

I read the [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Running_Unit_Tests_on_Jest.html#createRunConfigJest) about Jest and Rider and I have a question.
In package.json I have `scripts: {"test":"jest"}`, but this command not showing me a test-tree, only terminal with running tests. If I build configuration (see article) and start it, I will see a test-tree.
How should I add script in my package.json file to see test-tree?
React+ts